# Debug.DrawRay not showing in the scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, debugging, game-development

I've tried to look in all the similar questions but I can't seem to find what is the problem, I'm learning with a template followed by the instructions via video, but everything is working perfectly, the .cs file doesn't show any error or problem, I can run everything perfectly, except the function if

```
if (Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down, 0.1f))
        {
            Grounded = true;
        }
        else Grounded = false;
```

because once I press the key W, it "jump" and if I keep pressing the key it keeps "floating"
like flappy bird, I put also the Debug. Drawray in order to show this raycast but it doesn't show it in the editor, I tried changing the value from 0.1f to 100f but it doesn't show, I'm new in this so maybe is some punctuation or I made a mistake typing the code.

this is the entire code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class JhonMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float JumpForce;
    public float Speed;

    private Rigidbody2D Rigidbody2D;
    private float Horizontal;
    private bool Grounded;

    void Start()
    {
        Rigidbody2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        
        Horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");

        Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, Vector3.down * 0.1f, Color.red);
        if (Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down, 0.1f))
        {
            Grounded = true;
        }
        else Grounded = false;

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W) && Grounded)
        {
            Jump();
        }

    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2(Horizontal * Speed, Rigidbody2D.velocity.y);
    }

    private void Jump()
    {
        Rigidbody2D.AddForce(Vector2.up * JumpForce);
    }
```

if I put or not that "if" option the character does the same, don't know where I made my mistake, I checked around and it seems that is ok.

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Try to set `depthTest: false` so the ray is not blocked/hidden by any  objects (including e.g. this very same object)

Comment: I am not sure if you still have the problem but I ran into the exact same situation by following the same tutorial.

The answer is that **the ray will not be drawn until the game is under preview mode**. Following the tutorial, I had the feeling that the debug ray was going to be drawn at all times, but the reality is that in order to make it visible you have to run the game preview and then go back to the editor view.

Thanks. Hope my comment clarifies your doubts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Click `Gizmos` Make sure it is on, if you see Camera icon then its On
2. or Ray length is to small to see,
3. down to `#Scene`

You see `Shaded` Click and Change to `Wireframe`

```
private void OnDrawGizmos()//used to see Ray in editor without update function
{
  //your Ray code here
  //before i click play i like to hide this method 
 Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, Vector2.down * 1f, Color.white); // try this
}
```

Comment: Using the private void i could see the ray, i checked everything, Gizmos is on, the Ray lenght is ok (i tried also at 100f and couldnt see it), in #Scene i tried also Shaded, Wireframe and both, and nothing, why i cant see it using the simple Ray code in Update function?

Comment: Send Image what you trying to do ,i think your code is wrong, you using 2D.Raycast with Vector3 use Vector2.

Comment: @puzzlessouls doesn't make a difference .. in such case the `Vector3` are simply implicitly converted to `Vector2` by omitting the Z component

Comment: @puzzlessouls this is what was supposed to happen: https://ibb.co/tpF8JDdhttps://ibb.co/4ScbjsN

Technically and theoretically was suposed to happen also with the code as i wrote it, but don't understand why it doesn't happen. i wanted to know if this code

if (Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down, 0.1f))
        {
            Grounded = true;
        }
        else Grounded = false;

was working properly, so the ray was not too big or too small to touch the "ground" so it doesn't jump in middle air.

Comment: image link not work send another one